# Conditional mySQL statement. If true UPDATE, if false INSERT

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create more robust `MySQL` Queries and learn in the process. Currently I'm having a hard time trying to grasp the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` syntax and possible uses.

I have an `INSERT` Query that I want to `INSERT` only if there is no record with the same `ID` and name, otherwise `UPDATE`. `ID` and name are not `UNIQUE` but `ID` is indexed.`ID` isn't `UNIQUE` because it references another record from another table and I want to have multiple records in this table that reference that one specific record from the other table.

How can I use `ON DUPLICATE KEY` to `INSERT` only if there is no record with that `ID` and name already set else `UPDATE` that record?

I can easily achieve this with a couple of `QUERIES` and then have `PHP` do the `IF` `ELSE` part, but I want to know how to `LIMIT` the amount of `QUERIES` I send to `MySQL`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Note you need to use `IF EXISTS` instead of `IS NULL` as indicated in the original answer.

Code to create stored procedure to encapsulate all logic and check if Flavours exist:

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE `GetFlavour`//
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetFlavour`(`FlavourID` INT, `FlavourName` VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Flavours WHERE ID = FlavourID) THEN
UPDATE Flavours SET ID = FlavourID;
ELSE
INSERT INTO Flavours (ID, Name) VALUES (FlavourID, FlavourName);
END IF;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

**ORIGINAL:**

You could use this code. It will check for the existence of a particular record, and if the recordset is NULL, then it will go through and insert the new record for you.

```
IF (SELECT * FROM `TableName` WHERE `ID` = 2342 AND `Name` = 'abc') IS NULL THEN
INSERT INTO `TableName` (`ID`, `Name`) VALUES ('2342', 'abc');
ELSE UPDATE `TableName` SET `Name` = 'xyz' WHERE `ID` = '2342';
END IF;
```

I'm a little rusty on my MySQL syntax, but that code should at least get you most of the way there, rather than using ON DUPLICATE KEY.

Comment: Getting an error with this:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF (SELECT * FROM flavors WHERE id = '1' AND Name = 'BerryBlue') IS NULL THEN ' at line 1

Comment: @Vitaliy - I've updated my code. See if that helps you at all. If not, try putting the INSERT statement onto the same line as the IF statement.

Comment: Tried that already. Also reversed the logic and still gives me a syntax error. I even replaced all PHP vars with static values with no luck.

Comment: @Vitaliy - I've added another code snippet that works (i tested it a few more times than usual to make sure).

Comment: You must use IF/ELSE inside of a MySQL function or procedure, it doesn't work like a regular query.

Answer (score 4):

> id and name are not unique but id is
> indexed. id isn't unique
>
> How can I use ON DUPLICATE KEY to
> INSERT only if there is no record with
> that id and name already set else
> UPDATE that record?

You can't. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE needs a unique or primary key to determine which row to update. You are better off having PHP do the IF ELSE part.

edit:

If the combination of name and id IS supposed to be unique, you can create a multi-column UNIQUE index. From there you can use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

Comment: +1 for explaining that fact. Sounds like he has an autoincrementing id column. In this case he just has to select then insert inside of a transaction.

Comment: Then this way I would need two queries. One to SELECT the fields and then another to UPDATE/INSERT. I'm trying to see if I can do this in just one query. I'm not autoincrementing the id column. The id refers to a unique id of another record on another table.

Comment: Unfortunately without a UNIQUE index, I don't think you can. Internally MySQL tries the insert first and then catches a 'duplicate key error' and then does the update. REPLACE works the same way. It sounds like perhaps id and name combined could make up a UNIQUE index? If so create that combined index and ON DUPLICATE KEY should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use a stored procedure, then you can embed all the logic there are plus you have a reusable piece of code (e.g. the stored proc) that you can use in other applications. Finally, this only requires one round trip to the server to call the stored proc.

Comment: I'm terribly new to SQL and don't know how to make stored procedures. I have a lot to learn.