# Conditional update/insert in MySQL

Tags: mysql, insert-update

I found here a topic about an MySQL IF, ELSE query,i adapted it but i can't figure it out what is the problem with it.

Here is the query:

```
IF (SELECT * FROM `jos_import03_07_2011` WHERE `cod_oem` = 'OP-4CL') IS NULL THEN 
INSERT INTO `jos_import03_07_2011` (`tip_imp`, `tip_produs`, `producator`,
    `cod_intern`, `desc`, `cod_oem`, `pret`, `valuta`) VALUES ('Imprimanta Laser', 
    'Piese Schimb', 'BROTHER', 'BR-200503', '', 'OP-4CL', '338.49', 'EUR'); 
ELSE UPDATE `jos_import03_07_2011` SET `pret` = '338.49' WHERE `cod_oem` = 'OP-4CL';
END IF;
```

And here is the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL     
server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF (SELECT * FROM   
`jos_import03_07_2011` WHERE `cod_oem` = 'OP-4CL') IS NULL THE' at line 1
```

This is the original post:

[Conditional mySQL statement. If true UPDATE, if false INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940283/conditional-mysql-statement-if-true-update-if-false-insert)

Thanks,
Sebastian

**UPDATE**

Error code for IF EXISTS:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL 
server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM 
`jos_import03_07_2011` WHERE `cod_oem` = 'OP-4CL') THEN' at line 1
```

Comment: If you look at the linked post, the OP over there had the same problem.  The accepted answer corrected IF (SELECT...) IS NULL to IF EXISTS.  Have you tried that?

Comment: yes, i tried that too. still doesn't work.

Comment: @sebastian: please post the error message you get when trying the other `IF EXISTS` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reason you can't use the [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax?

```
INSERT INTO `jos_import03_07_2011` (`tip_imp`, `tip_produs`, `producator`,
    `cod_intern`, `desc`, `cod_oem`, `pret`, `valuta`)
VALUES ('Imprimanta Laser', Piese Schimb', 'BROTHER', 'BR-200503', '', 'OP-4CL', '338.49', 'EUR')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET pret = VALUES(pret)
```

would be far more efficient: one less query and far less code to debug.

Comment: i can use On duplicate key. i just saw the other post and i thought it should work. with your code i get an error at `SET` and i do not know why.

Comment: it seems that there is no need for `SET`. it works with no erros, but it doesn't work i want it to. rows are still inserted even if i upload the same file again.

Comment: @sebastian: What is the primary key of the table?

Comment: @ypercube the primary key is an autoincrement number. but i want to check if the new insert has the same `cod_oem` column

Comment: @sebastian: Add a `UNIQUE KEY` constraint for field `cod_oem` and the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` will work ok.

Comment: Or for `(producator, cod_intern, cod_oem)` if there is possibility for two products having same `cod_oem`

Comment: @ypercube, thanks worked like a charm. the `cod_oem` field is indeed unique.