# Complex INSERT query

Tags: java, mysql, database, insert, innodb

I'm pretty new to MySQL. I have two related tables, quite common case: Klients(KID, name, surname) and Visits(VID, VKID, dateOfVisit) - VKID is the Klient ID. I have a problem with suitable INSERT query, this is what I want to do:
1.Check if Klient with specific name and surname exists (let's assume that there are no people with the same surnames)
2.If yes, get the ID and do the INSERT to Visits table
3.If no, INSERT new Klient, get the ID and INSERT to Visits.

Is it possible to do in one query?

Comment: does not sound like one query.

Comment: there is a related question , maybe this could help 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940283/conditional-mysql-statement-if-true-update-if-false-insert

Comment: how about a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the IF EXIST / NOT EXISTS and use a subquery to check the table.  See the reference bwlo

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

HTH

Comment: this does not give the solution

Answer (score 1):

The INSERT statement allows only one single target table.

So the query you're looking for is just impossible unless you use triggers or stored procedures.

But such problem is commonly solved using the fallowing small algorithm:

1) insert a record in table [Visits] assuming the parent record does exist in table [Klients]

```
INSERT INTO Visits (VKID, dateOfVisit)
SELECT KID, NOW()
FROM Klients
WHERE (name=@name) AND (surname=@surname)
```

2) check the number of inserted records after query (1)

3) if no record has been inserted, then add a new record  table [Klients], and then run (1) again.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
IF (SELECT * FROM `sometable` WHERE name = 'somename' AND surname = 'somesurname') IS NULL THEN
INSERT INTO Table1(name,surname) VALUES ('somename', 'somesurname');
ELSE INSERT INTO visits(kid,name,surname)
    SELECT kid, name, surname FROM Table1 WHERE name = 'somename' AND surname = 'somesurname';
END IF;
```

there is no need to specify 'VALUES' on the second insert

i have not tested it, but this is the general idea of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: It looks like it suits my needs, by I'm getting 1064 error[pre][code]IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `Klients` WHERE `surname`='Smith') THEN
INSERT INTO `Klients`(`name`,`surname`) VALUES ('Adam', 'Smith');
ELSE INSERT INTO `Visits`(`VKID`) 
    SELECT `KID` FROM `Klients` WHERE `surname`='Smith';
END IF;[/code][/pre]

Comment: Sorry but I can't figure out how to format piece of code in my comment, it's a bit messy

Answer (score 1):

These should be two queries in a transaction:

```
INSERT INTO Klients (name, surname)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
KID = LAST_INSERT_ID(KID);

INSERT INTO Visits (VKID, dateOfVisits)
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), NOW());
```

The first statement is an upsert statement where the update part uses not widely known, but intented exactly for the purpose functionality of LAST_INSERT_ID(), where explicitly passed value is stored for getting the value afterwards.

UPD: I forgot to mention that you would need to add a unique constraint on (surname, name).